# Printer Data Cables with *suspected* IC boards

Tags: digital-communications

I've one found of those printer data cables that have some kind of pair integrated circuit along them, one at each end just before the plugs, I was wondering if there is a less invasive way of determining the specs for them other than slicing their enclosure.

I'm sure it will be fine in doing so, and I know I'm over thinking this just a tad but I just feel uncomfortable with a pair of IC that isn't detected by windows, and if it were some kind of spying boom doogle it would probably have some kind spring/pressure based mechanism that wipes the microcontroller's programming or something of that nature

complete novice in this field apologies for any misuse of terminology and or incorrect terminology.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the devices you are asking about?

Comment: sure no problem, but like I said, the *suspected* ICBs are *along* the data cable, enclosed in a plastic  moulding cylindrical  in shape, and there are no other serial numbers on the cable, One end is standard USB. I will take as best photographs as I can

Comment: They could very well be just electrolytic capacitors, but why would it be necessary for USB?

Comment: They are probably ferrite beads - EMI suppression.  I don't think I have any on USB cables, but they're common on VGA and HDMI cables.

Comment: ok not to worry then it's just the only one I've ever seen before, and from my experience of fooling around with electrical trash back in the day all of the above would generally be found within the hardware enclosures, I guess I am just curious as to what would necessitate such things for 1m cable, but I guess if I open it up I might also find it's a relic of sorts

Comment: sure upon closer inspection it does look every bit like a pair of standard capacitors

Comment: I'm guessing the best bet would be to insert needles approximating the terminal locations and I can call it a day in the electrical engineering department (lol)

Comment: There are no terminal locations on a ferrite bead.  It is not electrically connected to the cable.

Comment: no I was referring to the case of them being capacitors

Comment: but to put a full stop to this on a circular fridge magnet of roughly the same diameter of the bulge in the cable was very clearly attracted

Comment: so they must indeed be ferrite beads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those black lumps are noise supression beads especially if they are heavy and stick to magnets.

eg: https://nz.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Fair-Rite/2643540202?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsuct6UGZJC7V3VDI5SybAbaF8BfY3CDFQ%3d

Comment: ok so if run a smart phone magnetic sensor in it's vicinity this should there abouts confirm what you are saying right?

Comment: @Adam No, that won't work. They're not magnetized, they just stick to magnets. Just like how your refrigerator sticks to magnets, but isn't a magnet itself.

Comment: ah of course how sad to see how low  my 0.75  BSc(physics) has fallen in the decade that's elapsed since

Comment: I have some mercury switches but now I'm thinking that type of magnetism would be too weak as well. Oh well I'm going to grab some of Mum's fridge magnets and if I feel a tug it's NS beads, if I don't they are capacitors. I would normally gamble on blackjack odds but I guess ill just pat myself on the back if I guessed right when I slice it open

Comment: you'll need a fairly large magnet as the magnetism has to go through the plastic covering to reach the magnetic part.